# Create job to run sp_tblLog_insert on 6 am on every day. Run job

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the code that runs insert at 6am but it doesn't work I don't understand why

```
 BEGIN
 DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job (
   job_name        => 'tblLog_insert',
   job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
   job_action      => 'BEGIN my_job_procedure; END;',
   start_date      => ('29-NOV-2016 10.43.30.000000000 AM +06:00','DD-MON-RRRR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=english'),
   repeat_interval => 'freq=hourly; byminute=0; bysecond=0;',
   enabled         => TRUE);
END;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check out [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add more details on what you've tried and the error message you're getting. This will help others give viewing your question to give you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert job_type to `STORED_PROCEDURE` with the following datetime formatting through use of `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ()` conversion

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(
             job_name    => 'tblLog_insert',
             job_type    => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
             job_action  => 'MYSCHEMA.MY_JOB_PROCEDURE',
             start_date  => TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('29-NOV-2016 10.43.30 PM +06:00',
                                            'DD-MON-RRRR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR',
                                            'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=english'),
             repeat_interval => 'freq=hourly; byminute=0; bysecond=0;',
             enabled         => TRUE
  );
END;
/
```

Comment: can you say more

Comment: BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(
   job_name    => 'inserttbllog',
   job_type    => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
   job_action  => 'MYSCHEMA.MY_JOB_PROCEDURE',
   start_date  => TRUNC(SYSDATE + 1) + 6/24,
   repeat_interval => 'freq=hourly; byminute=0; bysecond=0;',
   enabled     => TRUE
   );
END;

Comment: in the first case TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ format conversion was missing @NguyenTrongNghia111 ( You'd better to leave the original question, eg. no need to edit )